# Crashlytics.log not showing in Fabric Dashboard

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am using Crashlytics and fatal crashes get delivered.
However the data added with

```
Crashlytics.log(mytext);
```

is not showing anywhere in Fabric Dashboard.

I couldnt find any hint on a necessary setup or configuration in the docs.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Custom logs, keys and user identifiers are included on a per crash basis. To view them, go from your [image: Crashlytics dashboard.] and click on a specific issue.

Then click on "View All Sessions"[image: View All sessions]

and you'll see the most recent session and specific data:[image]

One thing to note is that you need to set this on each launch of the app once you know the values. They are not persisted across multiple launches.

Comment: But how can I see custom logs in dashboard if I do not have any issue?

Comment: That's not possible currently Krishna. Custom logs are only uploaded when non-fatal exceptions or fatal exceptions (crashes) occur in the same app session.

Comment: Hike @MikeBonnell can you elaborate on What you meant by "One thing to note is that you need to set this on each launch of the app once you know the values. They are not persisted across multiple launches."

Comment: Also @MikeBonnell looks like only couple of lines from the log are visible (2 lines)  not all the logs I add to the activity is visible on the above page you mentioned.

Comment: Sure, so each time the user launches an app a new record of their logs is created. If no crash happens, then the logs are discarded. For each launch of the app, you would need to re-log the information.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the logs using the following way.

I added an "**UPLOAD LOGS**" button on my application's settings page so when the user clicks on it the following will happen.

```
                        Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Upload Log exception"));
                        Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(thisActivity, SettingsActivity.class);
                        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
                        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(thisActivity,mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)thisActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 200, mPendingIntent);
                        System.exit(0);
```

The above code would invoke a non fatal exception which will upload all the logs of the current session to crashlytics and then restart the app after 200ms which is a requirement for crashlytic to upload the logs to remote (Because invoking non fatal error does not restart the app like a fatal crash does)

Comment: But remember, for any individual app session, only the most recent 8 logged exceptions will be stored this way.